# Magento 2 - Amazon Pay Error

Tags: magento2, amazon, amazon-payment

Having problem with Amazon Pay, not able to use amazon details to checkout and complete order whilst being a Guest user.

BUT

Can use amazon details to complete order whilst logged into the actual site with an account.

// EDIT //
[image]
this error also appears when trying to check out with amazon details